# Alternative to finfo(FILEINFO_MIME)->buffer() in Linux command line

Tags: php, linux, mime-types, content-type

Instead of using `finfo` on files to retrieve the `content-type` you can execute a command in linux

```
if(PHP_OS == 'WINNT'){
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $content_type = $finfo->file($file);
}
else{
    $content_type = shell_exec("file -bi $file");
}
```

If you want to retrieve the `content-type` of a file as a string you can do this

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$content_type = $finfo->buffer($data);
```

But is there an alternative to get the `content-type` of the file contents as a string in the linux command line?

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative: Use `finfo` on both Linux and Windows.

By the way: You have a shell command injection vulnerability. The filename is not escaped - thats what functions like [escapeshellargs()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) are for. Always use them!

Comment: I don't want to use finfo because it's not reliable

Comment: You do use it. Why isn't it reliable?

Comment: because it does only look at the file extension.. I only use finfo as a fallback

Comment: You are wrong. The fileinfo extension does look at the file's content.